# material-ui / data-grid flexible column width min-width

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

The material-ui data-grid (also x-grid) API doesn't allow to use "flex" and "width" for the column definition. When the flex is set to true, then the width is omitted but I would expect that if I set e.g. flex: true and width: 250, the column will be flexible but the width can't be less than 250 if I'm resizing the data-grid container.
Has anybody resolved this problem somehow?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `minWidth` instead of using `width` with `flex`.
(look at fluid width at https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns)
for example:

```
columns={[
  {
    field: 'id',
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 150,
  }
]}
```