# MUI DataGrid dynamic width according to longest data for column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using DataGrid from MUI and inside GridColDef I dont use anything related to width, I want to have columns to have width of longest data so that every letter is shown, is it possible?

Below is my GridColDef:

```
{
field: 'lastLogin',
type: 'dateTime',
headerName: 'Last login',
align: 'right',
headerAlign: 'right',
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use minWidth, see here - [material-ui / data-grid flexible column width min-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162583/material-ui-data-grid-flexible-column-width-min-width)

It has been a while since I have used any of that myself but I do remember having a minWidth with elipsis.

Comment: thanks but this only to define minimum width, if I define it 150 and column is taking 200 px still I cant show all of data

Comment: @BerkCan ever find a good solution for this? Wondering if it would have to be custom coded to use a state object for column width and choose value based on length of longest item in grid. But...such a hassle....